# While using Spring MVC I am trying to insert a table data to another one using @Controller but don't know how

Tags: sql, spring-mvc, jsp, model-view-controller, datatables

I am trying to transfer by insert from a table to another table in @Controller 
I will explain here better,
So I have an Employee table  and i want to transfer  first name . last name and function , to the Monday table, but I don't really understand how I can do it .[image: Tables]

here are some code i did PS. the language is Romanian so Luni = Monday the rest is is obvious.

I have all the CRUD implemented

WeekdayDAO

```
public class WeekdayDAO {



    public void insertLuni(Luni luni) throws SQLException{

        Connection conn = DBHelper.getConnection();


        String insertString=" INSERT INTO luni (nume, prenume, funcite) SELECT nume, prenume,funtie FROM employee WHERE id=?"  ;


        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertString);

        stmt.setString(1, luni.getNume() );
        stmt.setString(2, luni.getPrenume());
        stmt.setString(3, luni.getFunctie());
        stmt.executeUpdate();



        DBHelper.closeConnection(conn);



    }
```

Calendar controller

Explanation : so I need to create a link when i chose an employee by id to just add all the data I requested in Monday, because after that I want to show it in a table like all the Employees I added in that day.

```
@Controller
public class WeekController {

@RequestMapping(value = "detalii/{employeeId}")
public ModelAndView getEmployeeDetails(@PathVariable String employeeId) throws SQLException {

    EmployeeDAO edao = new EmployeeDAO();
    Employee employee = edao.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
    edao.getEmployeeById(employeeId);



    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    model.put("employee", employee);

    return new ModelAndView("employee/detalii", "model", model);

}




    @RequestMapping(value = "detalii/{employeeId}"/addEmployeeDay.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addEmployeeDay(@PathVariable String employeeId, Model model) throws SQLException {

        EmployeeDAO edao = new EmployeeDAO();
        Employee employee = edao.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
        edao.getEmployeeById(employeeId);

        WeekdayDAO wdao = new WeekdayDAO();
        Luni luni= wdao.insertLuni(luni);

        return new ModelAndView("employee/edit", "model", model);
    }
}
```

Other example is trying to change some stuff from the edit Employee but it doesn't work .

```
@RequestMapping(value = "editEmployee/{employeeId}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditForm(@PathVariable String employeeId, Model model) throws SQLException {

        EmployeeDAO edao = new EmployeeDAO();
        Employee e = edao.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
        model.addAttribute("employeeForm", e);

        return new ModelAndView("employee/edit", "model", model);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need two tables for. You can add another column in Employee named updateDate and then select the Employee by date.

Comment: @MagdalenaFairfax I'm new to this :) haven't tought about it but il definetly try it, i want to make a work plan calendar for personal project and didn't know how to ptoperly use sql

Comment: Then the best thing is to add another table and use OnetoMany and ManyToOne relationship between tables. You can check this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many . It helped me a lot.

Comment: have to finish the project by tomorrow , i tried the many to one and one to many method for like 3 days but something didn't work so i tried to find another way to do it, tough after I finish the java course I'm attending , I will try it again . but its weird that we are not thought anything about using Entity and OnToMany stuff we only used RequestMapping and Controller

Comment: What error did you got when trying  OneToMay annotations?